# Decoding binary string message

Tags: java, beginner, strings, programming-challenge

I am trying to learn some Java on my own, and I am tackling some "programming challenge" problems to practice the little I have learnt so far.

Could anybody constructively critique this beginner's effort [(source on Bitbucket)](https://bitbucket.org/robottinosino/topcoder_java/src/2bf27cffa902/src/com/topcoder/srm144/div1/BinaryCode.java?at=default)?

```
public class BinaryCode {
  public String[] decode(String message) {
    int messageLength = message.length();
    return new String[] { decodeMessage(message, messageLength, 0),
        decodeMessage(message, messageLength, 1) };
  }
  private String decodeMessage(String encodedMessage, int messageLength,
      int assumedFirstDigit) {
    StringBuilder decodedMessage = new StringBuilder(messageLength);
    int nextDecodedDigit = assumedFirstDigit;
    for (int i = 0; i < messageLength; i++) {
      if (nextDecodedDigit != 0 && nextDecodedDigit != 1) {
        return "NONE";
      }
      decodedMessage.append(nextDecodedDigit);
      int encodedDigit = encodedMessage.charAt(i) - '0';
      int decodedDigit = decodedMessage.charAt(i) - '0';
      nextDecodedDigit = encodedDigit - decodedDigit;
      if (i > 0) {
        nextDecodedDigit -= decodedMessage.charAt(i - 1) - '0';
      }
    }
    int checkValue = decodedMessage.charAt(messageLength - 1) - '0';
    if (messageLength > 1) {
      checkValue += decodedMessage.charAt(messageLength - 2) - '0';
    }
    if (checkValue == encodedMessage.charAt(messageLength - 1) - '0') {
      return decodedMessage.toString();
    }
    return "NONE";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These critiques are mostly style and syntax related, and do not address your algorithm (you could probably find the simplest possible algorithm with Google anyway).

- make `decode` and `decodeMessage` static
- explicitly hide the constructor for `BinaryCode`, e.g.

  ```
  // hide constructor
  private BinaryCode() {}
  ```
- remove unneseccary `- 0` from `encodedDigit` and `decodedDigit` declarations
- let `decodeMessage` calculate `messageLength` (fewer parameters are nearly always better)
- avoid using magic numbers and string literals (`-1`, `-2`, `"NONE"`, etc...)
- create method `lastChar` and call it instead of `messageLength - 1` e.g. `int checkValue = lastChar(decodedMessage) - '0';`

  ```
  private static char lastChar(CharSequence sequence) {
      int lastIndex = sequence.length() - 1;
      return sequence.charAt(lastIndex);
  }
  ```
- replace `decodedMessage.charAt(messageLength - 2)` and `decodedMessage.charAt(i - 1)` with `previouslyDecodedChar` e.g.

  ```
  char previouslyDecodedChar = '\0';
  for (int i = 0; i < messageLength; i++) {
      // ...
      if (i > 0) {
          nextDecodedDigit -= previouslyDecodedChar - '0';
      }
      previouslyDecodedChar = decodedMessage.charAt(i);
  }
  int checkValue = lastChar(decodedMessage) - '0';
  if (messageLength > 1) {
      checkValue += previouslyDecodedChar - '0';
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments. I really appreciated them. `- '0'` is not redundant. The method signatures were mandated by the exercise, and I "think" the instantiability is too, so I could not hide the ctor.